# С новым, 2019 годом! (О Новом годе, русском языке и нашем сайте)

Tags: обсуждение

Хочу поздравить всех с Новым годом и пожелать всего самого наилучшего в уже наступившем 2019-м!

А заодно поделиться своими мыслями о новогоднем празднике, русском языке и нашем сайте, а точнее о том, что их объединяет в моем сознании. Хотя Новый год значительно моложе (праздник в его нынешней секулярной редакции родился в 1935 году), он стал явлением русской и "русскоязычной" культуры, почти такой же "скрепой", как и сам русский язык. Русский (советский) Новый год с его атрибутикой и традицией — явление уникальное, зачастую непонятное тем, кто отмечает New Year. Не зря в английской Википедии (и еще на семи языках) есть отдельная статья [Novy God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novy_God). Очень важно то, что Новый год, как и русский язык и русская культура, не забыт теми, чьи корни — в большой стране под названием CCCР (это мы наблюдаем и на нашем сайте). Именно язык, культура и такие традиции, как Новый год, — лучшие "агенты влияния", лучший "клей", настоящий предмет гордости. И я верю, что они сильнее и долговечнее любых политических или религиозных противоречий и территориальных споров. Именно на них нужно делать ставку. А это значит, что наш сайт идет "верной дорогой" :-)

Comment: О корректном написании "С новым, 2019 годом!" см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447372/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)